# Solve for n if $\frac 45(n-10)=\frac {-8}9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Should I distribute the $\frac 45$ first, or find a common denominator between $\frac 45$ and $\frac {-8}9$ and then distribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac 45(n-10)=\frac {-8}9$$

$$\frac54\frac 45(n-10)=\frac54\frac {-8}9$$

$$n-10=\frac {-40}{36}$$

$$n-10=\frac {-10}{9}$$

$$n=\frac {-10}{9}+10$$

$$n=\frac {-10+90}{9}=\frac {80}{9}$$

Answer (score 1):

neither.  multiply both sides by 5/4

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by $\frac54$ on both sides...  Get $n-10=-\frac {10}9$...  Now add $10$ to both sides. ..  Get $n=10-\frac  {10}9=\frac  {80}9$...